# Global variable in multi-threading/multi-tasking environment

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, global-variables

I have a scenario where i have to load a large json file into memory from server containing key:value and approx 300 threads will search value from that json variable.Json variable will be only read by all threads.What is the best way to do this? Will my global json variable create problem in multithreading?

Comment: If it is readonly, I don't see any problems, if the threads would be modyfing it, that would be troublesome.

Comment: Have a look at [ThreadLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If all the threads are read-only you don't need a lock mechanism at all. It is implicitly thread-safe. :))

Comment: Thanks Jakub and Supun for your comments :)